# Splitting a column in mysql database to two columns

Tags: mysql

I am trying to split a column into two and compare to find duplicate values in my column.

The following is an example of data in my column

```
'ETORHHF000224000023305'
'ETORHHF000002000000623'
'ETORHHF000002000000624'
'ETORHHF000002000000625'
'ETORHHF000002000000626'
'ETORHHF000002000000627'
'ETH0001845254525 '
'ETH0001845264526 '
'ETH0001845274527 '
'ETH0001845284528 '
'ETH0001845304530 '
```

The query to get all this id in my database is

```
select * from animals
```

I have found the following solution online but it is for *Microsoft SQL Server* and I am not able to make it work for *MySQL*

```
SELECT m.name,
       LEFT(m.name, CHARINDEX("\", m.name) - 1) AS column1,
       RIGHT(m.name, LEN(m.name) - CHARINDEX("\", m.name)) AS column2
FROM MyTable m
```

Comment: What is your desired output?  You posted a SQL Server query, but even if we translate to MySQL it won't work.

Comment: my desired output is to split the words from  numbers which i can then compare to check for duplicates

Comment: Are the letters always in the same position and width?  If not, then you can't really do this in MySQL.

Comment: the letters are always in the same position; i only want to compare 12 numbers from the right to check for similar records

Comment: No, not accoding to your sample data.

Comment: the width is different but i want to split 12 numbers from the right and compare the numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql (>= 8) and MariaDB (>=10) support some regular expression functions.

If you use at least those versions, you could do:

```
select 
  name,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '\\d+\\s*$', '') as letters,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '^[a-zA-Z]+', '') as numbers
from animals;
```

An [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c36ba34de30ea7341895a125d00fa0ca)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to flag the 12 digits on the right of each entry when those digits are duplicate, then you may try the following query:

```
SELECT
    RIGHT(entry, 12) AS entry,
    MIN(entry) AS first,
    MAX(entry) AS second
FROM animals
GROUP BY RIGHT(entry, 12)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

If you also wanted the full duplicate records, then you may use:

```
SELECT *
FROM animals
WHERE RIGHT(entry, 12) IN (
    SELECT RIGHT(entry, 12) AS entry
    FROM animals
    GROUP BY RIGHT(entry, 12)
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Comment: is it possible to put the duplicate column side by side